# i am using p-tableCheckbox and i want to click using Cypress

Tags: cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

i got a problem i am using p-tableCheckbox and I want to click it using Cypress

i tried
cy.get('[id="pr_id_2-table"]').find('div').contains('role="checkbox"').click();

but it's not working any help is heighly appreciated

Comment: Please add the error screenshot, DOM structure for this element to check your locators,  and share the URL if accessible outside.

Comment: Add the HTML that you are working with.

Comment: Iam sorry the html was very long :(

Answer (score 1):

most probably this will work

`cy.get('#pr_id_2-table [role="checkbox"]').click();`

Comment: This did not worked for me as I'm using new prime ng controls in new angular

Answer (score 1):

`.contains()` is for finding text, but `role="checkbox"` is an attribute.

You should search for it with square brackets, same way as `[id="pr_id_2-table"]` but using `.find()` to search inside the previous subject.

```js
cy.get('[id="pr_id_2-table"]')
  .find('div')
  .find('[role="checkbox"]')
  .click()
```